# How to estimate two unknown parameters of a equation

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, parameter-estimation, artificial-intelligence

The equation is 
$$
y(x) = ab^2x^2 + abx + g(x)
$$

I know $x$, $y(x)$ and $g(x)$, I want to estimate $a$ and $b$.

And I want to optimize $a$ and $b$ with future data of $x$ and $y(x)$.

Comment: Do you want to do this with some software or not? Lots of programs can do this (it is called fitting).

Comment: Have you heard about smallest squares estimation?

Comment: Looks like standard nonlinear least squares to me...or you could take logarithms to turn it into linear least squares. Which is appropriate depends on the scale that you have in mind.

Comment: I want to write a algorithm. 
For fitting I think I need a lot of data, but i dont have a lot of data at once. I need a method that works iteratively. 
I don't understand how to separate a and b and estimate because they are together in the equation.

Comment: A method that takes data in a "stream" and makes a "small update" with each additional data point is not likely to give good results in a problem like this.

Comment: I have an idea of how much the upper and lower limits of a and b should be. Anyway I just want to estimate. Not expecting 100% correct answer.

Comment: If I can use ADALINE (Adaptive Linear Neuron) to estimate a*b^2 and ab, then I can find the parameters a b. Do you see any problem with this? I will try the least square method also.

Answer (score 1):

A procedure for fitting is shown below :

[image]